# In compositor 2 images overlay each other

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency, layers

I have two objects on two different layers. Gem and surface plane. I also use HDRI and because of that I can't disable "Use environment" option in Render Layers menu. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWcCkQ3943Y) in goal to achive glare effect on gem stoune. But in the compositor I either loose surface or loose gem stone. What nodes should I use to preserve either surface mesh and gem. [image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *Color > Alpha Over* node to combine both layers, then use the Diamond layer Alpha channel map as mixing factor.

Make sure you created a proper alpha map in the Gem layer so it can be properly combined.

Comment: Remember to enable film>transparency so that the layer with the gem has an alpha channel to be used with the alpha over node proposed on the answer.

Comment: In addition, I had to rerender layers with that film=>transparency option to aqcuire alpha channel.